# Невалидный YMKPlacemarkMapObject

Tags: yandexmapkit

По клику на pin сохраняю его в качестве свойства, и через какое-то время мне нужна данные, но объект карты устарел, поэтому вынужден сохранить user Data отдельно, хотелось бы понять почему объект протухает?

Comment: А это не связано с тем, что MapKit хранит слабые ссылки на передаваемые ему Listener-объекты. Необходимо самим хранить ссылку на них в памяти? https://yandex.ru/dev/mapkit/doc/ru/android/quickstart#work

Comment: мне нужно userdata сохранить отдельно?

Comment: private var selectedMapObject: YMKPlacemarkMapObject?
я сохраняю вот так, но доступа к userdata нет, потому isValid = false

Comment: Вам лучше минимально собранный пример приложения в поддержку Яндекса отправить, чтобы они могли на код глянуть и по существу ситуации сказать. Со слов понять, какие именно данные берузтся, как, и куда сохраняются будет сложнее.